# Grails g:formRemote auto-retrieve

Tags: jquery, grails

I have this problem in my view area wherein I have this `<g:select>` tag having an `onChange` attribute to retrieve the data referenced to the selected value of the said tag. Unfortunately, we've containted the `<g:select>` tag inside the `<g:formRemote>` so that the data will be retrieved via the URI of the `<g:formRemote>` without having to refresh the page.

```
<!-- The g:formRemote of the view -->
<g:formRemote name="formRemote" uri:[controller:'test', action:'functionCall']>
   <g:select name="selectedValue" from="${['AA','BB']}"/>
   ${returnData}
</g:formRemote>

//The closure where the formRemote will be calling [TestController.functionCall]
def functionCall(){
   println 'entered'
   def returnData = ''
   if(params.value == 'AA')
      returnData = 'aaa'
   else if(params.value == 'BB')
      returnData = 'bbb'       

   [data:returnData]
}
```

The problem is we can't find a way to retrieve the model data from the controller back to the view [in reference with `<g:formRemote>`] upon change of value of `<g:select>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recenlty know that we didn't need a `<g:formRemote>` tag to have the theory to work. We lack the `onChange="${remoteFunction ...}"` parameter to the `<g:select tag>` following the format below:

```
<g:select 
   name="selectedValue"
   from="${['AA','BB']}" 
   optionKey="<the id of the model with reference to line#9>"
   onChange="${remoteFunction(
     controller:'test', 
     action:'functionCall',
     update:[success:'updateDiv'],
     params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
     onComplete='displayVal(this)')}"/>
```

Where the `updateDiv`,also located in the `.gsp`, is responsible of holding the view to be render from the controller with the closure `functionCall`.

```
<div id="updateDiv"></div>
```

And the TestController.functionCall having this contents:

```
def functionCall(){
   println 'entered'
   def returnData = ''
   if(params.value == 'AA')
      returnData = 'aaa'
   else if(params.value == 'BB')
      returnData = 'bbb'       

   render(view:'<can be a template or an html page>', model:[data:returnData])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select tag does not have to be inside a formRemote tag, a regular form tag with a remoteFunction call will do the trick.

From http://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP:

select tag in gsp:

```
<form>
    <g:select
        optionKey="id" optionValue="name" name="country.name" id="country.name" from="${Country.list()}"
        onchange="${remoteFunction(
            controller:'country', 
            action:'ajaxGetCities', 
            params:'\\'id=\\' + escape(this.value)', 
            onComplete:'updateCity(e)')}"
    ></g:select>
    <g:select name="city" id="city"></g:select>
</form>
```

javascript function in gsp to send data to grails controller:

```
<g:javascript>
    function updateCity(e) {
        // The response comes back as a bunch-o-JSON
        var cities = eval("(" + e.responseText + ")")   // evaluate JSON

        if (cities) {
            var rselect = document.getElementById('city')

            // Clear all previous options
            var l = rselect.length

            while (l > 0) {
                l--
                rselect.remove(l)
            }

            // Rebuild the select
            for (var i=0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                var city = cities[i]
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.text = city.name
                opt.value = city.id
                try {
                    rselect.add(opt, null) // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
                }
                catch(ex) {
                    rselect.add(opt) // IE only
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // This is called when the page loads to initialize city
    var zselect = document.getElementById('country.name')
    var zopt = zselect.options[zselect.selectedIndex]
    ${remoteFunction(controller:"country", action:"ajaxGetCities", params:"'id=' + zopt.value", onComplete:"updateCity(e)")}

</g:javascript>
```

grails controller:

```
import grails.converters.*
class CountryController {

    def ajaxGetCities = {
        def country = Country.get(params.id)
        render country?.cities as JSON
    }
}
```